# PHP $GET variable works with one value but not with another. why?

Tags: php, variables, url, get, echo

I am trying to retrieve user inputs from a previous page using the URL. I have the following code on the previous page which sends the username and account status via the URL.

```
header("location: pagename.php?user=$username&status=$status");
```

On *'pagename.php'* I have the following code which stores the values in local variables and echos them for my benefit.

```
if(isset($_GET['user'], $_GET['status'])){ 
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['user']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['status']);
echo $user.' - '. $status;
}
```

While, elswhere, this method works perfectly for retrieving 5 values form the URL, on this occasion I am failing to retrieve the status and it echoes the following *'username - '* You can see an image of the output for better understanding. I would much appreciate your assistance in helping me retrieve the status from the URL using PHP.

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/378892/c50c452d8597f2ac29970a6a21bfcc62

Having tried `var_dump($_GET)` I get the following result:
[image: Result of trouble shooting as suggested in the comments by Marc B.]

Comment: I don't think your `isset()` syntax is correct. I think you need to check for both variables individually.

Comment: !max: it's perfectly fine. isset allows multiple args, and only returns true if they're all set.

Comment: @MarcB you're right. My bad.

Comment: @rumesh: basic debugging, `var_dump($_GET)` and see what PHP received.

Comment: Unless you have register globals turned on, `$user`, `$status` will not have the respective GET values (this setting might differ from server to server). You might want to read the GET values into a variable to display them.

Comment: Try doing `$user = $_GET['user']; echo $user;` and see if it works. Same for the `satus` variable too.

Comment: Shouldn't you be echoing ***echo $_GET['user'].' - '. $_GET['status'];***

Comment: @DavidCorbin you are right but OP's code might still work if register globals setting is on. http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yep but I assume it isn't for debugging purposes.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to add the $username and $status variables in my code...I have just edited it.

Comment: When I tried var_dump($_GET) I get the following: array (size=2)
  'user' => string 'testuser' (length=8)
  'status' => string '0' (length=1)

Comment: You should note that 0 equals false in PHP. Try it with other values for status.

Comment: I tried other values knowing that but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that the issue lied with the naming of the variable `$status`, which incidentally happened to be the same name used in my login session and because I was not logged in it did not get the account status. I fixed the issue by simply renaming the variable.